# MongoDB endless Find ToListAsync

Tags: c#, winforms, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I'm attempting to retrieve data from a MongoDB collection, however something strange is happening. If I show a MessageBox the data fetch works, if I don't it doesn't.

```
static class MongoDBController {
    static MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");

    public static async Task<List<Course>> GetCourses(string dbName = "school") {            
        // Get our course collection
        var db = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Course>("courses");

        // Create an empty filter
        var filter = new BsonDocument();

        // Use the empty filter to get all courses from the database
        return await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

The code above gets the content out of the database, the code below - found in my `Form1.cs` - places it inside a ListBox.

```
private void FillCourseList() {
    Task<List<Course>> courseTask = MongoDBController.GetCourses();

    MessageBox.Show("Fetching worked (yay!)");

    // get the result
    List<Course> result = courseTask.Result;

    // Show every course found in the resultset
    foreach (Course s in result) {
        listBox_overview_vakken.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Now if I remove the *Fetching worked (yay!)* pop-up my listBox never gets filled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what can cause such behaviour (some tricky thing with SynchronizationContext?), but I recommend you to read http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html.

Comment: this `courseTask.Result` is a blocking call, to take advantage of `async`, you may want to change your `FillCourseList` to `private async Task FillCourseList` and do an `... result = await courseTask.ConfigureAwait(false);` You should also "bubble" the `async/await` signatures all the way up for the methods in your call stack.

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for your input on this, allowed me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the issue, as Alex kindly pointed out, is making the `FillCourseList` asynchronous aswell. This allows the program to continue running while the data is fetched from the database. The blocking call I had before apparently was the cause of the issue. This does add the need for [thread-safe calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the Windows Form though.

```
    private delegate void SetListCallback(List<Course> result);

    private async Task GetCourseList() {
        Task<List<Course>> courseTask = MongoDBController.GetCourses();
        List<Course> result = await courseTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

        // When finished, fill the listbox
        FillCourseList(result);
    }

    private void FillCourseList(List<Course> result) {
        // If the calling thread's ID doesn't match the creating thread's ID
        // Invoke this method on the correct thread via the delegate
        if (this.listBox_overview_vakken.InvokeRequired) {
            SetListCallback d = new SetListCallback(FillCourseList);
            this.Invoke(d, result);
        } else {
            foreach (Course s in result) {
                listBox_overview_vakken.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A good answer, including the marshaling back to the UI thread

Comment: `async void` is ment only for top level event handlers. Use `async Task` instead