# How to prevent MongoDB C# from retrying a failed login

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, credentials

We're creating an audit-testing tool which is deliberately trying to log into all of our Mongo servers using invalid credentials (non-existent user).  It's purpose it to allow us to track that the failed login is getting logged by our auditing software.

After upgrading to the latest MongoDB C# drivers, we're noticing unwanted behavior, also witnessed in the VS debugger.  I'm seeing multiple retries to the server and the following lines repeated over and over in the debugger window when I get to the `var query` line in the code below - which also corresponds to dozens of hits in our auditing tool - suggesting that it is in-fact connecting to the server using our invalid credentials as desired.

> Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException' in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException' in mscorlib.dll

At no time, does the `catch` block ever hit, and I'm having trouble finding any configurations that would disallow retrying logins.  I would expect the failed login to bubble up so I can catch it, rather than what is occurring.  This is the block of code from the console app in C#.

```
            SqlDataReader rdr = sql.ExecuteReader(); 
            // reader contains server names and connection strings to be used below.
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    var svr = rdr[0].ToString();
                    var cstr = rdr[1].ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + svr);


                    var conn = new MongoClient(cstr);

                    var db = conn.GetDatabase("admin");

                    var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
                    var query = coll.Find(_ => true).ToList();
                    var str = coll.ToString();


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Error processing: " + ex.Message); 
                }


            }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The latest driver is all async, so the `Find()` call is some async call now. I'm not terribly versed in this, so I would read maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131387/mongodb-endless-find-tolistasync). All examples of `Find` on the new driver use `ToListAsync()` that i've seen, not `ToList()`. The [Getting Started](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/) page shows this syntax: `var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();` -- this might get the exception bubbling up as it should, currently I think your `Find` is returning immediately.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Changing to `ToListAsync()` only had the effect of delaying when the errors appeared in the debugger, but not raising them up the stack.

Comment: What about adding `await` to the beginning of the call?

Comment: That had the same effect.

Comment: have you tried to put the reader  inside try-catch block?

Comment: Well, mongodb C# driver is open source, so you can branch it and do changes needed: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

Comment: @mcNets, Yes.. There is no visible exception bubbling up.

Comment: @Eckd - Unfortunately, I wish I had time to muddle through 120k lines of someone else's code - which is why I posted here.